# WooCommerce Email on Payment Done but not received to Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know which WooCommerce email is sent to the admin when user has done the payment, money left from the user (bank) account, but admin haven't received the amount. Is there an email trigger for this situation by default ?

Comment: this should maybe be on some other StackExchange network but unsure which one.

Answer (score 2):

The new order email to the admin looks for the order status to switch to Processing (it also looks at other states, but Processing is the one relevant to your question). The payment gateway will decide what makes an order "paid" (and thus Processing in WooCommerce), so the answer to your question may vary with different providers.